# How can I add pagination and how can I change thumbnail size?

Tags: php, loop, pagination, post-thumbnails

I'm currently learning wordpress development and I try to add pagination which displays a "older"/"newer post" link and the number of the current page at the bottom of the posts. I also try to change the thumbnail size to 200x200px and all images should be cropped.

Here is my current wordpress loop:

```
<main id="main">

        <?php 
        // the query
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 10 );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        ?>

        <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

            <!-- loop -->

            <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

                        $the_query->the_post(); ?>
   <article id="post"> 

                <div id="thumbnail">

                    <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array( "class"=>"thumbnail")); } ?>

            </div>

           <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

           <div class="entry">

                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

           </div>


   </article>


        <?php } } else { ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Die Posts entsprechen leider nicht den Kriterien.' ); ?></p>
        <?php }  ?>

       <!-- end of the loop -->

       <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</main>
```

I tried various things to add a new image size but nothing worked for me.

It currently looks like that: http://prnt.sc/b3v88w I just want to scale it up from 150x150 to 200x200px.

Comment: Please edit your question: ask only **only one question**, open a second question for thumbnail problem.

Comment: Since the thumbnail part has already an answer it might be better to post a new question for the pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your **functions.php** file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 200 );
```

Read More: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size

Comment: Nothing changes, sorry.

Comment: try `'the_post_thumbnail(thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'thumbnail' ))`